# In how much time can i learn Russian language?

Tags: узус

I m visiting Tashkent in April. Is it possible to learn Russian in a months time ??

Comment: If you don't have any background knowledge, then it's not possible at all. Plus, going to Tashkent, you'd probably find Turkmen language more useful.

Comment: Turkmen language would be in Ashgabad, not Tashkent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's actually not about any aspect of Russian language

Answer (score 1):

Category II: Languages with significant linguistic and/or cultural differences from English
44 weeks (1100 class hours) ([Language Learning Difficulty](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Language_Learning_Difficulty_for_English_Speakers)) assuming you'll spend half of this time in Russian enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know any slavic languages, then it is not possible to learn it in a month. it's the second most difficult language for English speakers after Chinese.

it is possible to pick up simple conversational phrases like "thank you", "check, please", "left-right", numbers etc. you will not be able to understand anything Russian talk about on TV or in the public transport

also, depending on what would be your environment and who would be your hosts in Tashkent, you may not be able to hear much Russian at all. the local language in Tashkent is Uzbek, which is as different from Russian as English. obviously most urban people speak Russian, but why would they be speaking to you or in front of you in Russian unless they're ethnic Russians? if your hosts are ethnic Russians, then it's a different story, of course, if you spend most of your time with them. otherwise in public places, I would expect most conversation be in Uzbek